# Cannot point the domain to the right Droplet

Tags: wordpress, web, digital-ocean

I setup a droplet on digitalocean and pointed the domain to it. I have installed wordpress on the droplet (express setup), but I cannot figure out how to get it up and running. I can access a page without graphics when I type in the ip address of the domain, but when I try to go to the webpage, I get an error from Cloudflare which I installed on the previous instance of wordpress.

These are some of the screens:

[image: Website]

[image: wordpress page when I enter the ip address on the browser]
[image: domain info]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Figured it out. I had to change the IP on cloudflare to get to the right page.